# Regarding System.Object Constructor class in c#

Tags: c#, constructor, object-initializers

Object class constructor is called in the constructor of the class when an object is created . What happens in the Object Constructor?

Comment: Why this voted as unclear?

Comment: sorry . I did't understand you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Reference Source for object](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs), this is the code for the constructor:

```
// Creates a new instance of an Object.
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public Object()
{            
}
```

Nothing happens there.

In the comments you ask how the class members are initialized to their default value. The `Main()` method in the following program...

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
        }
    }
}
```

is translated by the compiler to the following MSIL:

```
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApp1.Program::.ctor()
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  ret
```

The interesting instruction here is [newobj](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj(v=vs.110).aspx). Which among other things:

> allocates a new instance of the class associated with ctor and initializes all the fields in the new instance to 0 (of the proper type) or null references as appropriate.

So [newobj](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj(v=vs.110).aspx) initializes all class members to some type of `0` or to `null`.

In the comments you ask what happens if you initialize a field to a specific value. If we modify the program above:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private int i = 1;

        public Program()
        {
            i = 2;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();
        }
    }
}
```

We have added a field `i` that is initialized to `1` and a constructor that sets `i` to `2`.

The MSIL for the constructor of the `Program` class looks like this:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0002:  stfld      int32 ConsoleApp1.Program::i
IL_0007:  ldarg.0
IL_0008:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
IL_000d:  nop
IL_000e:  nop
IL_000f:  ldarg.0
IL_0010:  ldc.i4.2
IL_0011:  stfld      int32 ConsoleApp1.Program::i
IL_0016:  ret
```

So now,

- [newobj](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj(v=vs.110).aspx) creates the object and initializes it's memory (setting `i` to `0`).
- The constructor of `Program` runs and `ldc.i4.1` followed by `stfld ... i` sets `i` to `1`.
- Then the constructor of the base class `System.Object` is called.
- And then (still in the constructor of `Program`) `i` is set to `2` (`ldc.i4.2` followed by `stfld ... i`).

So effectively `i` is set 3 times (to 0, 1, and 2) and when the constructor of the base class runs `i` has a different value then when the constructor of `Program` finishes.

For the order in which initializers and constructors run see [these](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/) [posts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: there is no functionality.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing going on there. Did you expect to see something?

Comment: yes .If I use a zero parameterized constructor with no functionality, who does all the initialization of members ?

Comment: If I initialize member variable during declaration then according to you it is first initialized to 0 then to the value that I will be providing. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, all memory associated with the object will be cleared (set to zero) and if in your code you initialze a field to a non zero value it will be set to that value after that.

Comment: @NagasivaniSiddana Note that if you have field initializers, the constructor is modified (added if missing) to include the initializers. See for example [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACgcBmIgJgIGECBvKgzoutAOxgIANAgF4CxPHgqUAvkA). Look at the `ctor` in the right pane, and try adding a constructor in the left pane.

Comment: if in case there is a static class variable and I create no object then does it initialize to zero who does it ?

Comment: @NagasivaniSiddana: Your questions are all answered in the language specification, which I recommend you read. If you have a static field with no initializer in a type that is never constructed, then it is initialized to zero *at some time before any static field is accessed*. If no static field is accessed and no member is created then *it is impossible to read the field*, so it doesn't matter whether it is initialized, or even allocated.